# python rewrite lfilter (iir) with for

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, infinite-impulse-response, deconvolution

It's a beginner question, but useful to users from python - `signal.lfilter`, I was using `lfilter` from 
[Find reverse one pole lowpass filter](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36479/find-reverse-one-pole-lowpass-filter)

The doubt now is, how to rewrite the iir filter to 'revert' the low pass filter, without using `lfilter` function:

low pass:

```
y[i] = y[i-1] * 0.8702 + x[i] * 0.1298
y[i] = signal.lfilter(b,a,x)
```

low pass revert:

```
y[i] = y[i-1] * ?? + x[i] * ?? + ??
y[i] = signal.lfilter(a,b,x)
```

Answer (score 1):

from:

```
a[0]*y[n] = b[0]*x[n] + b[1]*x[n-1] + ... + b[M]*x[n-M]
                      - a[1]*y[n-1] - ... - a[N]*y[n-N]
```

rewrite to:

```
a=[0.1298]
b=[1,-.8702]

a[0] * y[n] = b[0] * x[n] + b[1] * x[n-1]

y[n] = ( 1 * x[n] + -.8702*x[n-1] )/.1298
```